# NaN column after using map and replace attribute

Tags: python

I have a dictionary:

`label_to_text:{0: 'emotion1', 4: 'emotion2', 10: 'emotion3', 12: 'emotion4', 14: 'emotion5', 23: 'emotion6'`

and a df:

text_df:

```
index    emotion    
  0         0
  1         10
  2         23
  3         12
  4         4
  5         14
```

What I try:

I used `map` to add a new column with the dict.values():

`text_df['text'] = text_df['emotion'].map(label_to_text)`

But I got this:

text_df:

```
index    emotion     text
  0         0        NaN
  1         10       NaN
  2         23       NaN
  3         12       NaN
  4         4        NaN
  5         14       NaN
```

What I expected:

text_df:

```
index    emotion     text
  0         0        emotion1
  1         10       emotion3
  2         23       emotion6
  3         12       emotion4
  4         4        emotion2
  5         14       emotion5
```

I also tried with `replace` instead `map`, but I got this:

```
index    emotion     text
  0         0        0
  1         10       10
  2         23       23
  3         12       12
  4         4        4
  5         14       14
```

This is an image of my dictionary:

[dict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMxqP.png)

when I used `value = label_to_text.get(3)` I got the value, so the key is correct I think.

Edit: Dict information added.
dict print:
[dict print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWdAp.png)

print(text_df['emotion'].dtype):
[text_df['emotion'].type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD9zR.png)

Comment: Your `label_to_text` is an invalid dict. Can you `print(label_to_text)` and include it to your Q ?

Comment: also what is `print (text_df['emotion'].dtype)` showing

Comment: I added the information that was requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `NaN` because the keys of your dictionnary are numeric while the values of your column are strings. So, you need to [`strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) extra whitespaces, [`cast`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to (`int`) and then you can proceed the [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) :

```
text_df["text"] = text_df["emotion"].str.strip().astype(int).map(label_to_text)
```

Output :

```
print(text_df)

  index emotion      text
0     0       0  emotion1
1     1      10  emotion3
2     2      23  emotion6
3     3      12  emotion4
4     4       4  emotion2
5     5      14  emotion5
```

Comment: Thank you! this works and and I understood the explanation!. to the right hand side of the line in `text_df["emotion"] =text_df["emotion"].str.strip().astype(int).map(label_to_text)` must be `text_df["text"]` instead `text_df["emotion"]`. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome and thanks as well for the good catch, I updated my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can update each row base on information from another column with `df.at` like this:

```py
for i in range(len(text_df)):
  text_df.at[i, 'text'] = label_to_text[int(text_df.at[i, 'emotion'])]
```

Comment: This works!. Although I would also like to know why `map` doesn't work, it should work fine as I used it